# QT: Command for compile qt files

Tags: c++, linux, qt, command-line

I need to compile a qt application on the linux command line but i have some problems including qt libraries

these are the includes on my program:
InterfazArchivador.cpp:

```
#include "InterfazArchivador.h"
#include "ui_InterfazArchivador.h" 
#include <iostream>
#include <QMainWindow>
```

InterfazArchivador.h:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
```

Main:

```
#include "InterfazArchivador.h"
#include <QApplication>
```

I've tried with something like this:

```
gcc -m32 -c -I/home/sandarka/Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets /home/sandarka/Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qwidget.h /home/sandarka/Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtGui  main.cpp ArchInterfaz.cpp
```

but i get errors like:

```
/home/sandarka/Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qwidget.h:37:31: fatal error: QtGui/qwindowdefs.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio 
#include <QtGui/qwindowdefs.h>
                ^
 compilation terminated.
 In file included from /home/sandarka/Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/QMainWindow:1:0,
             from ArchInterfaz.h:4,
             from main.cpp:1:
/home/sandarka/Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qmainwindow.h:37:31: fatal error: QtWidgets/qwidget.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio 
#include <QtWidgets/qwidget.h>
                    ^ 
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/sandarka/Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/QMainWindow:1:0,
             from ArchInterfaz.h:4,
             from ArchInterfaz.cpp:1:
/home/sandarka/Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qmainwindow.h:37:31: fatal error: QtWidgets/qwidget.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio
#include <QtWidgets/qwidget.h>
                           ^
compilation terminated.
```

I don't know what is wrong, maybe I need to include more libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use both include path:

```
gcc -m32 -c -I/home/sandarka/Qt/5.4/gcc/include/ -I/home/sandarka/Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets -I/home/sandarka/Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtGui  main.cpp ArchInterfaz.cpp
```

basically you have to pass the compiler two paths:

- the one who global contains all Qt modules
- the one who contain the single Qt module you want to use

Why two paths for the same file?

Inside a Qt module, other files are included with the `<QtModuleName/FileName>` rule, without the module name you have to tell manually to the subdirectory in which to search, otherwise the compiler will expect the file in the Qt include root.

Comment: Thak you for the answer, it works i don't have those errors anymore but now i'm getting  fatal error: ui_InterfazArchivador.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio
 #include "ui_InterfazArchivador.h" do younow how to solve that?

Comment: you haven't compiled the .ui file, `uic InterfazArchivador.ui -o ui_InterfazArchivador.h` should do the work

Comment: oh, and how I compile the .ui from the command line? I tried at the final of command above but the error persist.